# sql direct way to get number of rows in table

Tags: sql, mysql, sqlite, postgresql, rowcount

Hi again people of stackoverflow.
I have a routine that has a step that I find unnecessary
lets say you want to get all the images from a gallery, and limit a certain number of images per page.

```
$db = PDO object
$start = (pagenum x images per page)
$limit = (images per page)
$itemsdata = $db->query("SELECT id,name FROM gallery LIMIT $start,$limit")->fetchAll();
$numitems = $db->query("SELECT id FROM gallery")->rowCount();
```

`$imgsdata` is a array of all the images in a gallery for example.
`$numimgs` is the number of images that the gallery has.

you would need `$imgsdata` to do a foreach loop on each image in the array, while
`$numimgs` is needed to generate the page numbering (e.g. << 1 **2** 3 4 >>)

my grudge is with `$db->query("SELECT id FROM gallery")->rowCount();`
It feels completely like some sort of cheat, isn't there a direct way to get the number of rows in a table, something like `SELECT gallery.Rows`?

p.s. currently I'm using SQLite, but I'd need it for MySQL and PostgreSQL as well.

Comment: it's so simple... well that's what you get for being self taught...

Comment: what's the page numbering (<< 1 2 3 4 >>) called anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will tell you the number of rows:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM gallery
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple count() aggregate function will return the number of rows quickly

```
Select count(*) from table
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select count(*) from gallery
```

Answer (score 1):

Me too!

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM gallery
```

Yes, this should work the same just fine in MySQL, SQLite, and PostgreSQL.