# How does one get the number of rows in an SQL database?(Android SDK)

Tags: android, sql, database

I looked for this on SO and saw this(and others like it): [sql direct way to get number of rows in table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3408669/sql-direct-way-to-get-number-of-rows-in-table), however, Select is shown as a token as is count. I tried to use mDb.execSQL() but that only returns void. Any help on how to do this would be appreciated. The code is:
public int getRowNumber(){ return mDb.execSQL("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM notes");} I get an error that says "cannot return void result".

Comment: What is your code like? It shouldnt be returning void. The method in that answer you posted is correct

Comment: public int getRowNumber(){
     return mDb.execSQL("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM notes");} I get an error that says "cannot return void result". Thanks for looking.

Comment: read documentation again .... execSQL is not for queries!!!!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you're getting means your method can't return `void.`  `execSQL` itself returns a void, and you're returning that same void from your own method which is declared to return an int:

```
mDB.execSQL(...); // returns void
return mDB.execSQL(...); // re-returns void

public int foo() {
    return void; // error!
}
```

[d.android.com link for reference.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#execSQL%28java.lang.String%29)

---

I know you already accepted, but here's a quick & dirty test method that does what you sort of need to do:

```
    public int testCount() {
     Cursor c = m_db.rawQuery("select count(*) from mytable", null);
     int tst = 0;
     if (c.moveToNext()) {
         tst = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("count(*)"));
     }
     c.close();
     return tst;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, how do I get it to not return void and return the result of what I had it execute?

Comment: Seeing as you can't change the return type of `execSQL`, you'll have to do something else like `query` and read the returned Cursor to find the int value of the result, then return that from your method.

Comment: Np!  Updated with a quick example.

Answer (score 1):

mDB.execSQL(...); returns void and your select query return counts that is why you are getting error. Instead you may use query (or) rawQuery like mDb.rawQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM notes",null); which returns Cursor, from Cursor get the 'cnt'.